# Arrange Dom Element based on "order" attribute assigned

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm adding order property to the list based on order user selects the options. Once order attribute is added html looks like follow

```
<nav class="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul>
              <li class="li1" order="999">
                <a href="#" class="active">
                list1
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="li2" order="1">
                <a href="#">
                list2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="li3" order="2">
                <a href="#">
                list3
                </a>
              </li>
    <li class="li4">
                <a href="#" order="999">
                list4
                </a>
              </li>
    <li class="li5" order="3">
                <a href="#">
                list5
                </a>
              </li>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

browser shows as(ul has display flex):
list2
list3
list5
list1
list4

I want to rearrange DOM based on the order not sure how to do it using jquery:

```
<nav class="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul>
              
              <li class="li2" order="1">
                <a href="#">
                list2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="li3" order="2">
                <a href="#">
                list3
                </a>
              </li>
<li class="li5" order="3">
                <a href="#">
                list5
                </a>
              </li>
<li class="li1" order="999">
                <a href="#" class="active">
                list1
                </a>
              </li>
    <li class="li4">
                <a href="#" order="999">
                list4
                </a>
              </li>
    
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: why not use `style="order: value;"` as attribute which would work then within a flexbox by default.

Comment: Please see below what I'm trying to achieve. I've 4 divs and their relative anchor tags. 
Active class is being added to anchors on scroll when the order of the display elements is not changed. 
When the order of the elements changes, active classes are only being added to the sorted elements. 
I sorted nav anchors too based on the order. Active class is still not being added to anchors based on the scroll of the element.
Please help me add an active class to anchors based on scroll when nav and elements have the "order" attribute on them.
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2yds3u9/16/